# how to add another case for cover picture Android Studio

Tags: android, image, profile

**when i update my profile picture the cover image also updates automatically can anybody help me to add another case for cover image**

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Media.REQUEST_PROFILE_PICK: {
                final UploadTask uploadTask = Media.handleImagePick(getActivity(), data);
                updatePhoto(uploadTask);
            }
            case Media.REQUEST_COVER_PICK: {
                final UploadTask uploadTask = Media.handleImagePick(getActivity(), data);
                updatecoverPhoto(uploadTask);
            }

        }
        }
    }

 public static boolean Library1(Activity activity, int requestCode) {
    // pick from gallery
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");

    if (intent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),requestCode);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Media.REQUEST_PROFILE_PICK: {
                final UploadTask uploadTask = Media.handleImagePick(getActivity(), data);
                updatePhoto(uploadTask);
                break;
            }
            case Media.REQUEST_COVER_PICK: {
                final UploadTask uploadTask = Media.handleImagePick(getActivity(), data);
                updatecoverPhoto(uploadTask);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```